# Finding a limit on an unspecified function

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given that $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 3 $ and $ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = -2 $, find the following limits.

One of the limits that I was required to find was:

> $\lim_{x \to a} x^3 ln f(x)$

What does the "ln" mean, and what are the steps to solve this question?

Comment: I'm assuming that is $\ln$, which is natural logarithm.

Comment: @Student1058 Upon review, yes, it says ln. However I am still unsure what the steps are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont provide a full solution, but I will lead you on your path. The most important thing to recognize here is that $\ln{x}$ is a continuous function. This means that $\lim_{x\to a}\ln{x} = \ln{a}$ for any strictly positive $a$ that you can think of. So in fact we can move around the limit to where we like and distribute it across (since $x^3$ is also continuous). Which means that,
$$ \lim_{x\to a}x^3\ln{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}x^3 \times \ln({\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}). $$
And I believe you will be able to continue from here.